# Esperanto stress with dipthongs

Tags: pronunciation

I am having issues knowing the stressed (tonic) syllable, especially when a noun or adjective is pluralized. I am not sure if I should be treating endings like *-oj* and *-aj* as separate sounds or as diphthongs (the words *malgrandaj* and *hundoj* for instance.

Is *malgrandaj* pronounced /mal-gran-DA-y/ (with a Spanish sounding -a) or is it pronounced /mal-GRAND-aye/? Similarly, /HUN-doy/ or /hun-DOI-y/. The issue for me is knowing to treat it as a diphthong or not. Please help!!

Comment: I think that this topic is treated in the first lessons of virtually every Esperanto course.
Anyhow, it would make no difference whether -Vj- were two phonemes or one (a diphthong): In both cases they form one syllable, so the stress according to the rule is on the syllable before word-final -aj and -oj (and -aŭ: báldaŭ).

Comment: It might be, but I m sure people wouldn't ask if they weren't having trouble with it.

Comment: There is, of course, no such thing as a dumb question, but if you're having trouble with a question like this after working through a basic course, it's possible you haven't found a good basic course to work through. If you need help finding a good course, please ask.

Answer (score 9):

The whole point of J and Ŭ in Esperanto is to make it very clear whether it's one syllable or two. The vowels are just A, E, I, O, U; the second-to-last is stressed (marked with `´` in the examples below):

- malgr**á**ndaj h**ú**ndoj
- bal**á**i (ba-lá-i, a verb), b**á**laj (bá-laj, an adjective) — *That's why we use J for plurals and not I.*

Answer (score 3):

JC Wells in his *Esperanto Dictionary* states that the *aj* "represents **a** 
 plus a short **i**-sound; it is like English *y* in *my*".

Others:

- *ej* as in *play*
- *oj* as in *boy*
- *aŭ* as in *cow*

There is no English equivalent of *uj*, he gives *ruinous* as a close approximation.

So, to answer your question: they are diphthongs, rather than separate sounds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should treat it as a single syllable. The stress always falls on the second-to-last syllable. So *malgranda* and *malgrandaj* both have three syllables and so in both cases the stressed syllable should be the *gran*. Ie, */mal-GRAND-aye/*.